# Panning a bar chart in d3.js

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, bar-chart, pan

I'm new to d3.js and in my code below (which is also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLYaQ/)), I am experiencing 2 problems

1. The first `rect` being added seems to block the bar charts being added in the code below.  Panning using mouse drag on the `rect` seems to work!
2. Deleting the `rect` reveals the bar chart. But panning by dragging on the canvas no longer pans the view.

I want the bar chart to be revealed, and panning to work by dragging in the chart region. Any help strongly appreciated, thank you!

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/MLYaQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rect` which has the `zoom` should have `fill` set to `none`.
You need to do more than just reset the `axis` to pan the graph: you also need to redraw the `rects`. And it is ill-advised to use and override globals in the same file.

```js
function zoomed() {
    // Bar charts (Cannot be seen unless we delete rect from the code above)
    rects = d3.select('#chart svg')
        .selectAll('rect.data')
        .data(data, function (d) {
        return d.timestamp;
    });

    rects.enter()
        .append('rect')
        .classed('data', true);
    rects.attr('x', function (d) {
        return x(d.timestamp);
    })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
        return y(d.value);
    })
        .attr('timestamp', function (d) {
        return d.timestamp
    })
        .attr('width', 4)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

    chart.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    chart.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

}

    // ...

d3.select('#chart svg').append('rect')
    .classed('bg', true)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .call(zoom);

zoomed();
```

This is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MLYaQ/1/

You can [use clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to limit the visible region of the chart.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I am wondering why you used `.selectAll('rect.data')` instead of `.selectAll('rect')`, and also why you need to use `.classed('data', true)`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx I like to label the different `rect`s in the SVG depending on whether they are `bg` or `data`. It avoids oversellecting when I want to `update` one set without effecting the others.